# Add in visibility Issue with outlook 2016

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-store

We are publishing outlook add-in and its gets rejected saying it's not visible in outlook 2016 MSI.
Does it has something to do with the mailbox version as we are using 1.6 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook 2016 one-time purchase supports only 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4.

Read more about that in the [Outlook JavaScript API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets) article.

If you are still interested in installing Office 2016, see [Download and install or reinstall Office 2016 or Office 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-2016-or-office-2013-7c695b06-6d1a-4917-809c-98ce43f86479?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

Comment: What could be possible issue with add in not visible in outlook 2016 professional plus.
We have used mailbox version 1.6 in manifest file

Comment: Outlook 2016 one-time purchase supports only 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4.

Comment: With 1.6 It was visible and working on Outlook 2016 Click to run version. How then there is an issue with Outlook 2016 MSI

Comment: It appears if you are doing everything correctly. We will try to raise an issue with the validation team about this, but to speed up your process, you should resubmit and add a note, that because your add-in is APISet 1.6, it does not need to support Outlook 2016 MSI. It appears as if the validation team has made a mistake here.

Comment: According to MSDN, Outlook 2016 MSI doesn't support 1.6.